# Add Object to List with both Object and List defined in model C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following class and foreach loop. When I use the list.Add(sheet) code the newSheet object is added with no issue. The next line of code which should do the same but this time using the LisOfSheet Object fails to add the newSheet object and results in a null value for listOfSheets. What is the problem? Thanks.

```
public class Sheets
{
    public string SheetId { get; set; }
    public string SheetName { get; set; }
}

public class SheetListModel
{
    public List<Sheets> ListOfSheets { get; set; }
}
```

And the following foreach loop to populate a list.

```
List<Sheets> list = new List<Sheets>();
SheetListModel listOfSheets = new SheetListModel();
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    string sheetId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string sheetName = file.Name;
    Sheets newSheet = new Sheets() { SheetId = sheetId, SheetName =sheetName};
    list.Add(newSheet);
    **listOfSheets.ListOfSheets.Add(newSheet);**
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize the list `ListOfSheets` in the `SheetListModel`. Initialize the list in the constructor:

```cs
public class SheetListModel
{
     public SheetListModel()
     {
          ListOfSheets = new List<Sheets>();
     }

      public List<Sheets> ListOfSheets { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can achieve the same with the shorter syntax:

```
public class SheetListModel
{
    public List<Sheets> ListOfSheets { get; set; } = new List<Sheets>();
}
```

Comment: @rafCalg, if my answer helped you, please accept it and vote up for it.

Comment: Hi Oleg. I upvoted but due to my being an unreputable member of the stackoverflow community, my upvote will not display.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @rafCalg, yes, you're right, you can't upvote yet, sorry. However as author of question you can accept the answer ([check mark under the vote counter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)).